# How to set the href with the pathname of the current page in it?

Tags: 8, views, theming, blocks

Inside a view I have a block for which there is a field called Global Perspective.

Inside the block override , I have rewrite rules which overrides teh out of the field with custom text.

```
<div class="featured-media-tag">
{% if field_is_global_perspective__value %} 
    <a href="{{ path('view.global_memos.page_1', {'global_perspective' : 1}) }}" class="media-link">Global Perspectives</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{{ path('view.global_memos.page_1') }}" class="media-link">Global Memos</a>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

This gives me the relative path, i.e  `/global-memos?global_perspective=1` for the a tag.
When I click on my local the link it directs to `mylocal.sj/global-memos?global_perspective=1` but the issue is on production i have my site homepage as `example.com/mysite` .

So when I click on the a tag on production, it is going here `example.com/global-memos?global_perspective=1` , but expected is for it to go here `example.com/mysite/global-memos?global_perspective=1`.

I have tried to write a preprocess but failed at it.
function subtheme_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables) {

```
  // Retrieve an array which contains the path pieces.
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();

  // The hostname of the site
  $host = \Drupal::request()->getHost();

  if($host == "example.com") {
    $variables['pathname_id'] = "/councilofcouncils";
  }

}
```

and then tried to add the pathname_id to the rewrite rules like this
Global Perspectives

Comment: Have you tried `<a href="{{ url('<current>') }}`?

Comment: @DannyEnglander it worked. Thanks :) Please answer the question so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `{{ url('<current>') }}`. I could not find any documentation for this but it seems to work. For example, based on your code above, I can add the current URL like this in a Twig template:

```
<a href="{{ url('<current>') }}" class="media-link">
 {{ 'Global Memos'|t }}
</a>
```

If I am on a page with the url, `example.com/councilofcouncils`, the twig code above will render as:

```
<a href="http://example.com/councilofcouncils" class="media-link">
Global Memos
</a>
```